# Android GridView doesn't show item onclick with text and image

Tags: android, gridview, onclick

I'm new here and I'm completely confused about my Android project. I have done some research, but still I don't have the answer. My problem was: when I clicked on the item in GridView it showed me just black screen. When I changed something, now it shows me an error in Eclipse. I don't know where my mistake is.

I used this answer [Gridview with two columns and auto resized images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images) to make my gridview nice and suitable for multiple screens.

I used something from this one: [I want the Images which are on the gridView should show in full View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541942/i-want-the-images-which-are-on-the-gridview-should-show-in-full-view).

My code: FirstActivity:

```
public class FirstActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    ActionBar actionbar;
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

        items.add(new Item("Name1", "Text1", R.drawable.pic_12));
        items.add(new Item("Name2", "Text2", R.drawable.pic_13));
        items.add(new Item("Name3", "Text3", R.drawable.pic_14));
        items.add(new Item("Name4", "Text4", R.drawable.pic_15));
        items.add(new Item("Name5", "Text5", R.drawable.pic_2));

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, items));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                // Sending image id to SecondActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                // passing index (position of clicked item)
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
```

My ImageAdapter class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return items.get(i).drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.squareimageview, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        }

        picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);

        Item item = (Item) items.get(i);

        picture.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
        name.setText(item.name);

        return v;
    }

}
```

SecondActivity:

```
 public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.second);

            // get intent data
            Intent i = getIntent();
            // Selected image id
            int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

            TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_small);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_big);

            Item item = (Item) items.get(position);



      //***************HERE ARE MY ERRORS***************************************
            name.setText(items.name);
            text.setText(items.text);
            imageView.setImageResource(items.drawableId);

//**********************************************************************

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Item class:

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    int drawable;
    String text;

    public int getDrawable() {
        return drawable;
    }

    public void setDrawable(int drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    public Item(String name, String text, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.text = text;
        this.drawable = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

My layouts:
first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_big"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

squareimageview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.zva.app.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to pass list of items with that position

here you passed only position of that clicked items.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
  i.putExtra("id", position);
  startActivity(i);
```

you are passing null values that's y it showed blank page.

first you have to pass like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("item", items);
i.putExtra("id", position);
startActivity(i);
```

u can use list as static like this

```
static List<Items> items=new List<Items>();
```

in second activity u have to import like this

import static here declare package name.items;

and code like this

```
items.get(position).getName();
```

Comment: Now it underlines i.putExtra("item", items); I think you can't send ArrayList with Intent

Comment: ya u can not intent array list into another activity.instead of that u can use that list as static and in second activity u can access that list so u can get that list in second activity.then we use that list and use position in that list

Comment: To write: static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(); in both activities? It didn't change anything... :(

Comment: Please, could you help me?

Comment: import static package com.second_activity.app name.items;
To import like this?
When I write items.get(position).getName();  it underlines getName()

Comment: code like this :                                                public static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(); in FirstActivity and                                                 List<Item> items = FirstActivity.items; imageView.setImageResource(items.get(position).getDrawable()) in second activity it works!

Answer (score 0):

In your `SecondActivity.java` items list is **empty**. So, whenever you try to get an item from a position in empty list it will throw error.

First of all, try to add few items to the list and also check whether the size of the list is greater than the position which you want to get from the list.

Once the above corrections are made, you also have to change the following lines in your `SecondActivity`,

```
name.setText(items.name);
text.setText(items.text);
imageView.setImageResource(items.drawableId);
```

to,

```
name.setText(item.getName());
text.setText(item.getText());
imageView.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
```

Bcs, you can get the name,text,drawable values for a **single item** and not for whole **items list**.

**EDIT 1:**

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                // Sending image id to SecondActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                Item item = (Item) items.get(position);
                // passing index (position of clicked item)
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                i.putExtra("Name",item.getName());
                i.putExtra("Text",item.getText());
                i.putExtra("image",item.getDrawable());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
i.putExtra("img", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

**NextActivity**

`int img;` as **global**

```
Intent i = getIntent();

if(i != null)
    img = i.getIntExtra("img", 0);

LinearLayout main_lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_lay);
main_lay.setBackgroundResource(img);
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "try to add few items to the list"? I think there are enough items, so why do i need to add more? I checked position with LogCat and it's correct. When I copied your lines of code, it underlines 3 lines where are getName(), getText(), getDrawable(). I tried this method earlier, but it didn't work.. Error says: The method getDrawable() is undefined for the type ClipData.Item

Comment: You checked position with logcat.. thats ok.. Have you tried `Log.v("items_size--",""+items.size())` in your `SecondActivity`? You check that, it ll return 0.

Comment: Okay, it returned me 0. What can I do for that?

Comment: Please, could you help me?

Comment: @user2954913 it's not possible to get the values from that. so you can pass all the values on click from the intent.

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot because now i understood my mistake. :) By the way, how to get image via Intent? I think textview i should send converted to String and then write         name.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("Name")); but what about image? How to send image via Intent?