# GridView example not working

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-logcat

I am taking help from this link: [Android GridView Layout Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/). When I run my app my app stop working. I am getting following errors. **I want to create gridview that show thumbnail images in gridview and full size image on click. For this I am saving thumbnail and full image of each image in drawable. How to do this? please help me.**

ImageAdapter class-

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.kri1, R.drawable.kri2,
            R.drawable.kri3, R.drawable.kri4,
            R.drawable.kri5, R.drawable.kri6,
            R.drawable.kri7, R.drawable.kri8,
            R.drawable.kri9,R.drawable.kri7, R.drawable.kri8,
            R.drawable.kri9, R.drawable.kri7, R.drawable.kri8,
            R.drawable.kri9
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Logcat-

```
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541): Process: com.example.gridview, PID: 2541
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:575)
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:410)
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
02-20 07:06:19.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)
```

Comment: You are using `Bitmap`s of high resolution. instead load thumbnail images into memory

Comment: @GopalRao how to use thumbnail images? And I want to open full image on click on any image.

Comment: read how to handle `Bitmap`s [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) and sample project [here](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip)...

Answer (score 0):

You are using high resolution images so it gives great load on heap. Instead try down sampling images you are using on `getView()`.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
// set options for your need here
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context, yourImageId, options);
```

Comment: Where to use this code. And I have 9 images So which Id image I have to use?

Comment: You are getting references on getView() method as I said in the answer and each time you get image use above BitmapFactory methods to down sample images so that it does not fill your heap memory. Seems like images have high resolution. In your case mThumbIds[position] where you get references.

Comment: Can you change code in your answer according to my code. I am not getting you.

Comment: How to load large bitmaps effienctly: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Please read above link @user3126670 posted, its explaining your situation in a detailed way.